# Saving JSON data result in an incomplete file

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to save out a geoJSON file from OpenLayers 3. 
I have most of the code sorted but the resulting file is missing the CRS line,when I add it manually the file works just fine.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
var geoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var jsondata = geoJSON.writeFeatures(lyr_site.getSource().getFeatures(),    {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'},{dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'run.php', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
xmlhttp.send(jsondata);
```

The resulting file header looks like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":      {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.519087728539022,51.72285434232731],[0.5190669877274288,51.72334258224663],[0.5190633831708146,51.723622249385755],
```

And it should look more like this (I think)

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":       "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },

"features": [
```

Comment: Your coordinates seem to be in long-lat degrees which is the default in GeoJSON and used if crs is not defined. I believe that the file is OK but not any more if you attach that wrong crs into it. It that faulty GeoJSON then works for you, you may do something wrong.

Comment: Yes that file seems to have long-lat data, when I don't specify featureProjection or dataProjection I get the data in EPSG:3857 but no line in the geoJSON declaring the projection so the file doesn't work in my GIS.  I would be happy if the line was wrong but it just isn't there. `"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":       "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue myself. My project entails opening a GeoJSON file, adding/editing/deleting features, and then saving that file. Everything is using the 3857 CRS. However, OpenLayers could not open the file once I saved it due to missing the CRS object.

I could not find a way to add a parent level object via ol.format.GeoJSON, only features and geometries. So my workaround is to parse the GeoJSON string into JSON, add the CRS object, and then stringify which produces the same output as ol.format.GeoJSON.writeFeatures(). With this I can open, update, write, and then reopen in OpenLayers with no issue.

```
$('#saveButton').on('click', function (e) {
    var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var features = icsDataSource.getFeatures();
    var featuresGeoJSON = parser.writeFeatures(features);

    var featuresJSON = JSON.parse(featuresGeoJSON);

    featuresJSON.crs = {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" }
    };

    $('#debug').text(JSON.stringify(featuresJSON));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue in ol3 see https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2078

You can provide a patch.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I managed to get around the problem by using EPS 4326 and the resulting files are then readable. I would provide a patch if I was any good at writing code